# Acer aspire v3 771G ubuntu 13.04

Tags: acer, nvidia-optimus

Gooday, i have this acer and i have alot of boot problems (i suspect windows 8) 
and now i want to try ubuntu but when i use an usb to "try" ubuntu after the boot i get a black screen.

now ive read some of the forums and i found something about NOMODESET i have not tried this as i dont know what this does exactly.

now i have found this wiki entry https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee , i am by far no programmer and always reading all those commands have always kept me of linux because im scared i will !@#$ things up.

is there anyway i can go to NOMODESET in the ubuntu "trial" and can i also include the bumblebee futures (coding?) and in how many ways wil this affect my laptops perfomance?

reading the bumblebee entry its seems to be something about nvidia optimus and i dont reallt care much for the power saving, but will it affect any performance?

im not a heavy pc gamer but i like tho do some gaming and streaming and such also on a rather big TV in wich this laptop already has it flaws in some games not running properly on 65"

if this doesn't work or u advise me not to do this what else can i do to fix windows 8 or either some other linux version?

i thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bumblebee is something you can do after you've installed Ubuntu completely on your hard-disk.

Abouth the black screen after selecting "Try-Ubuntu".
You have to set the BIOS from "UEFI" to "Legancy BIOS".

Then you will get one screen further. Purple with two icons on the bottom.
Hit the [Esc]-key and choose your language.

With the next screen you can add options with [F6].
There you can activate "NOMODESET".

Select Try Ubuntu and start further.

The screen can go black and it can take a couple of minutes before the desktop can came up.

I hope I could explain it clearly enough.

Greetings, Erik